# Transaction using TransactionScope is not rolled back in a multithreaded execution path

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-5, sql-server-express, transactionscope

I have the following code:

```
Public Async Function Convert(schemaProgress As IProgress(Of ProgressReport), membersProgress As IProgress(Of Boolean), indexProgress As IProgress(Of Boolean)) As Task
   Try
        Using scope As New TransactionScope

            Await ConvertRootAsync()

            Dim schemaConversion = ConvertSchemaAsync(schemaProgress)

            Await ConvertMembersAsync(membersProgress)
            Await ConvertIndexAsync(indexProgress)
            Await schemaConversion

            scope.Complete()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Logger.ErrorException("", ex)
        Throw New FatalConversionException
    End Try
End Function
```

The various 'Convert' methods use `DbContext`'s `SaveChanges` method to add data to the database.

To test this out I produced a deliberate error in the ConvertMembersAsync method. The code in the `Catch`block is handled all right. But the SaveChanges operations that have been performed prior to the Exception are not rolled back.

The underlying provider is that for SQLExpress LocalDb.
The connection string:

"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=OurDb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDb.mdf"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a `DependentTransaction` to the Async methods. The Async method needs to insert this `DependentTransaction` in the contructor of a new `TransactionScope`. [It is documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.dependentclone.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).